# Chef - How to check if a bash block ran successfully and to ignore at the second instances

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am having a chef recipe with the following bash block -

```
bash "run_bash" do
user node[:value1][:user]
group node[:value1][:group]
cwd node[:value1][:install_dir] + '/tools/bin'
code <<-EOH
export MW_HOME=#{node[:value1][:mw_install_dir]}
export JAVA_HOME=#{node[:value1][:install_dir]}
export ORACLE_HOME=#{node[:value1][:install_dir]}
/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ./idmConfigTool.sh -configOAM input_file=#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/config.props
expect "Enter ID Store Bind DN password : "
send "#{OrcladminPassword}\r"
expect "Enter User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_SOFTWAREUSER: "
send "#{LDAPPassword }\r"
expect "Confirm User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APPSOFTWAREUSER: "
send "#{AppLDAPPassword }\r"
expect "Enter User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APP2ADMINUSER: "
send "#{App2AdminPassword }\r"
expect "Confirm User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APP3ADMINUSER: "
send "#{App3AdminPassword}\r"
sleep 240
expect eof'
EOH
```

I am trying to run this recipe with chef-solo.So redundantly this recipe will run.

I need a solution to make this bash block to be idempotent. There are guard statements like not_if,only_if etc. But i could not find a way to implement those guards here.

I thought of one solution which is,Once this bash block ran successful , i can find the time stamp and compare it with the current time stamp when the next run is happening. If those didn't match i can ignore running it.This is just a brute force work a round i can think.

Kindly provide a better optimal solution for this scenario.

Comment: I'd use a [not_if guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#not-if-examples) as the example with ::File.exists? targetting a file created during the installation.

Comment: @Tensibai:The bash block which i am trying to run which produces some '*.log' file but in the unknown location. Even if i give that '*.log' consider a situation if iam running on second time it will just skip this bash block. But some time the passwords provided in the expect block will be different.

Comment: Then I would create the script with a template and notifies an exécuté resource when the template change

Comment: That sounds workable. Can you pls give me a small code to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a template an using [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications):

`your_cookbook/templates/default/script.erb`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MW_HOME=<%= node[:value1][:mw_install_dir] %>
export JAVA_HOME=<%= node[:value1][:install_dir] %>
export ORACLE_HOME=<%= node[:value1][:install_dir]}
/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ./idmConfigTool.sh -configOAM input_file=<%=
Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] %>/config.props
expect "Enter ID Store Bind DN password : "
send "<%= @OrcladminPassword %>\r"
expect "Enter User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_SOFTWAREUSER: "
send "<%= @LDAPPassword %>\r"
expect "Confirm User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APPSOFTWAREUSER: "
send "<%= @AppLDAPPassword %>\r"
expect "Enter User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APP2ADMINUSER: "
send "<%= @App2AdminPassword %>\r"
expect "Confirm User Password for IDSTORE_PWD_APP3ADMINUSER: "
send "<%= @App3AdminPassword %>\r"
sleep 240
expect eof
```

`you_cookbook/recipes/default.rb`:

```
execute 'my_installer' do
  command '/usr/local/bin/my_script'
  action :noting # For it not to run on each converge by default
end

template '/usr/local/bin/my_script' do
  source 'script.erb'
  mode '0600'
  variables(
    'OrcladminPassword' => <how you set the value>,
    'LDAPPassword' => <...>,
    'AppLDAPPassword' => <...>,
    'App2AdminPassword' => <...>,
    'App3AdminPassword' => <...>
  )
  notifies :run,execute[my_installer]
end
```

You may add a `, :immediately` at the end of the notifies line to trigger the execution just have the template have been rendered.

This way chef will trigger the execute resource only when the template change.

This doesn't take in account cases where your install may not work and chef won't retry it in this case, the installation will stay failed.

All in all I would work with the product editor to have a kind of package to avoid this kind of brittle install.

Comment: Now i am able to see the code is running when the password changes. Just a small clarification. What happens at the first run of this code ,whether it takes the password whatever there in the templates and run it? and during the second time if we re ran it will just check the previous values in templates? . I just need a working logic of this scenario. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @HarishPC During the second time, the target file has not changed so the template resource doesn't notify the execute resource. I've added a mode on the script to avoid passwords being readable by everyone, and a link to the documentation of how notifications works.